# Android Small game

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener

I want build a small game in android in which bubbles to appear after a regular time gap.  And then disappear with equal intervals.  In the meantime player has to click all the bubbles which are appearing.

Could anyone suggest me a good method to implement this idea using view class and canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you want to use view class and canvas, but it seems that AndEngine might be a good thing to use for your game. Most of the heavy lifting is done by AndEngine. Look it up [here](http://www.andengine.org/) and get it from [git](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine)

Answer (score 0):

Look up information on SurfaceView, and if you want to have an idea of how to use it in a game sense look up the lunar lander example. That should help you get started, granted lunar lander is not exactly what you are looking for but it will help you understand what to do using a surface view.

Answer (score 0):

Developing these type of games using AndEngine is a cake walk. Use AndEngine framework,

[AndEngine Website](http://www.andengine.org/blog/)

[Sample tutorial which covers everything related to AndEngine](http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html)